# Ubuntu 13.10 - no USB devices after restart

Tags: usb, 13.10

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 13.10. I was trying to install wine and it hung up so I decided to restart the computer instead of killing processes at random (no, I didn't kill any processes). After reboot the keyboard (USB) doesn't function so I can't log in. USB wireless adapter is also down as is the USB mouse. I then installed 13.04 on side and it works just fine. Now the question is, how do I fix the 13.10 installation or should I just delete it and install 13.04 in it's place?

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is uninstall 13.10 and then do a reinstall. Most likely what happened is that Wine was in the middle of gaining access to USB devices so it could use your mouse and keyboard when you shutdown the computer and then the drivers got corrupted.

Comment: Downvote: That doesn't make any sense to me. If you know this is possible please describe how it can happen and some way to detect it.